# external drive mounts read only?

Tags: 20.04

Hi everyone going nuts with something here. I am trying to mount an external 8TB drive on Ubuntu (and also Xubuntu) and for whatever reason it mounts read only. It appears to be owned by root, and when I format I get a 64bit filesystem support not installed.

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `mount` options. In a terminal window, `mount` will show, OR Right click the disk's icon. Did the disk last work on Windows? Windows' "Fast Boot" option could have interfered.

Answer (score 0):

This was always a linux drive (no Windows here!)

This solution fixed it; I spent hours looking for errors when it was just a case of the drive being owned by root
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211159